# Dudas sobre set(Minimum|Maximum|Preferred)Size en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tuve un problema con un frame hecho en java para redimensionar sus componentes, y en una respuesta encontré que el uso de los métodos `set(Minimum|Maximum|Preferred)Size` no eran para nada recomendados en el establecimiento de las dimensiones tanto del frame como de sus componentes internos.

Ahora mi pregunta es, ¿Qué opciones puedo usar para cambiar estos métodos de redimensionamiento en mi código?

Comment: talves te pueda ayudar usando Layouts aqui teoria mas algunos ejemplos
http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Uso_de_Layouts